# MVC 3 Duplicated Controller names in AJAX post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

If from the page localhost:nnnn/Class I click on an AJAX link that will post to 'Class/AddClass' I get a RawUrl of Class/AddClass and it works just fine.

If from the page localhost:nnnn/Class/Index I click the same link I get a RawUrl of Class/Class/AddClass and it (obviously) doesn't work.

I realize I'm in Routing Hell, but who's rewriting the URL and why? I painstakingly stepped through the jQuery code and indeed it's posting to Class/AddClass.

Thanks for insight...
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not rewriting that is the problem. Your AJAX request is JavaScript and has nothing to do with the ASP.NET routing engine. When you use `Class/AddClass` you are making it relative to the location of the current URL. You can use `/Class/AddClass` which will resolve to the root of the site. That poses an issue if you are even in a virtual directory. I prefer to pull the full URL from a configuration file:

```
var url = '<%: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteURL"] %>/Class/AddClass';
```

With the appropriate entry in the web.config. This eliminates any guess work. You can also use `ResolveUrl`:

```
var url = '<%: ResolveUrl("/Class/AddClass") %>';
```

Comment: Thanks Dustin... using $.post('/Class/AddClass'...) makes it work. Though I am still puzzled who is duplicating the controller name in the previous example.

Comment: Oh wait... I get it! Relative to the location of the current URL means a post to Class/AddClass from Class/Index gives Class/Class/AddClass, as it should. Thanks again.